# 'Stereo mix" missing from Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series

Tags: dell-inspiron

I recently bought an Inspiron 15 3000 series laptop from Dell. The sound driver used in this laptop is 'Cirrus logic superior HD Audio'. I am trying to record audio coming from my Laptop speaker using Audacity. Even though I tried, windows WASAPI + Speakers (cirrus Logic) combination of settings in Audacity, it didn't work.I have windows 10 on my laptop

On investigation I found that my laptop does not have Stereo Mix as one of the Recording devices. Following is the screeshot

[image]

I tried to contact the Dell support but they were confused and didnt get any help. Could someone help me understand how to get Audacity record the sound from the speaker?

Comment: Stereo Mix is part of the sound driver, apparently the drive does not have that ability.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to record the system sound without stereo mix option in windows 10. I found this answer from audacity forum

1. Close and restart Audacity (or just launch Audacity if it's not currently running).
2. Set the "Project Rate" to 48000 (bottom left corner of the main Audacity window)
3. Start playing some sound from your web browser.
4. Click the Record button in Audacity